# How to clean up the git master branch

Tags: git, github

A couple of bad commits were merged with the upstream master, after which my feature branch also got polluted after I pulled from the upstream master. Using cherry picking- I am able to clean up the upstream master, but now if I merge my local code to the cleaned master, it again will get polluted.

I can't even discard all my local changes as there is quite a huge number of the same. Would a rebase help in this case- or any other way I can merge my local changes except for the bad code in the local.

Cherry picking on all the locals is not really an option as dev environment is highly distributed.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know git that well. I am still getting comfortable maintaining a remote master "bare" directory and moving changes back and forth between systems using the master. Can you declare a branch and start clean? I understand why you cannot throw out all the local changes. Usually, I would avoid a branch, but starting over without throwing things away sounds like a branch to me.

Comment: Well I could- but then there are almost 100 other developers- who wont'! But thanks for taking time to respond- really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Once the changes are upstream, you're lost. Of course, you could rebase, drop the bad commits and then `git push -f` but this is considered bad practice in a shared repo.

You could try to `git revert` the bad commits in reverse order. While the bad commits remain in the history, the bad code will disappear from the working copy.
The revert commits are then pushed to the upstream repo.

Comment: Well, "you're lost" generally is never the answer! Finally got it working with cherry picking and patching- but thanks for your response!